# Biblatex: volume is not changing textstyle

Tags: biblatex, biblatex-chem

I am trying to change the italic parts of the style `chem-angew` to slanted text, as the numbers are a bit less playful and more readable in slanted text than in italic.

I used `\DeclareFieldFormat{<field>}{<textstyle>{#1}}`, but it only changes the journal title to slanted text and not the volume. What am I doing wrong here?

This is the code I'm using

```
\usepackage{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    style=chem-angew,
  ]{biblatex} 
%
\addbibresource{bib.bib}
\AtEveryBibitem{%
    \clearfield{note}%
    \clearfield{doi}
    }
%
\DeclareFieldFormat{volume}{\textsl{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{\textsl{#1}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\DeclareFieldFormat{volume}{\textsl{#1}}` doesn't have the desired effect, because `chem-angew.bbx` has the following field format definitions for `volume` [(ll. 101-104 in v1.1y)](https://github.com/josephwright/biblatex-chem/blob/4dc024990a58da83a0711aaada716b68550359be/chem-angew.bbx#L101-L104)

```
\DeclareFieldFormat*{volume}{%
  \mkbibitalic{\bibstring{volume}~#1}%
}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{volume}{\mkbibitalic{#1}}
```

This means there is a type-specific formatting for `@article`s, so that `\DeclareFieldFormat{volume}{\textsl{#1}}` applies for all types, except `@article`s.

Try

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=chem-angew,
]{biblatex}

\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{\textsl{#1}}

\DeclareFieldFormat*{volume}{%
  \textsl{\bibstring{volume}~#1}%
}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{volume}{\textsl{#1}}


\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: "E. Sigfridsson, U. Ryde, Journal of Computational Chemistry 1998, 19, 377–395." with slanted italics]

For consistency you probably want all italics in the bibliography to be `\textsl`, which can be achieved by redefining `\mkbibitalics` and `\mkbibemph` (along with their 'internal definition')

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=chem-angew,
]{biblatex}

\makeatletter
\renewrobustcmd*{\mkbibitalic}{\textsl}
\protected\long\def\blx@imc@mkbibitalic#1{%
  \textsl{#1}\blx@imc@setpunctfont\textsl}

\renewrobustcmd*{\mkbibemph}{\mkbibitalic}
\def\blx@imc@mkbibemph{\blx@imc@mkbibitalic}
\makeatother


\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed answer and espacially for the code to change the textsytle for everything, that was what I was trying to do manually. 
It works great!